# Steam web api: How to get the tags for items in Steam Inventory

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

I'm currently trying to use the steam web api to get the tags items in a player's steam inventory.

An example of what I'm looking for is shown below:

[image]

I'm been looking at the [steam web api](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI), but I haven't found any methods that return the tags on a steam inventory item.

Does anyone know how to grab this? Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want specifically these tags: check your console while you switching games inventories. There will be ajax request link.

For example for TF2: [http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/YOUR_STEAM_ID/inventory/json/440/2/](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/YOUR_STEAMID/inventory/json/440/2/)

Replace "YOUR_STEAM_ID" with some user steamid64. 
If you want other game inventory: change "440" with(570 - dota2, 620 - portal2, 730 - csgo, 753 - steam inventory). 
Also with steam inventory you have to change following to it number(1 - gifts, 6 - cards, there also 3 and 7 numbers for other items)

Request that link like other api methods. It will return json, that you have to decode/parse.

Then watch "rgDescriptions" array. There will be your tags.

Comment: could you explain the ajax request link? I'm trying to develop this for the ios platform, so would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: I did not clearly understand your problem. I must explain how to get these links or how to use them? Updated my answer.